# Pgfplots: Discrete instead of connected values

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a table with experimental data. The table has two columns separated by a semicolon. The first column is the value for the x-axis and the second one is the y-axis value.

If I use the general `\addplot table {}` command, `pgfplots` draws a plot where it connects the points together. As the data points in question are discrete values, there should not be a connection between them, but rather should every point be drawn independently.

What's the correct approach for this using `pgfplots`?

#### Output generated by the `\addplot table {}` command

[image: default output]

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
    57.7200;403.7083
    81.1200;359.9954
    83.7600;2673.1575
    84.4800;201.8542
    95.7600;359.9954
    104.6400;403.7083
    104.8800;2673.1575
    105.0000;5146.4829
    105.1200;11393.4863
    105.2400;5706.3101
    105.9600;201.8542
    106.9200;4277.3057
    107.2800;359.9954
    107.4000;682.9842
    107.8800;2673.1575
    108.0000;403.7083
    108.3600;2673.1575
    108.6000;201.8542
    109.2000;47.6190
    109.4400;3883.1460
    109.9200;4081.7891
    110.0400;1113.2275
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {\textit{m/z}},
        ylabel = {Int. [\si{cps}]},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark = none, red] table[
            col sep = semicolon
        ] {table.csv};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Expected output

[image: expected output]

This output was generated by a little "hack". To have the correct axis, I drew the plot as before but changed the color to `red!0` so that it is transparent. Then, for each table entry, I manually drew the lines with the `\draw` command. It goes without mentioning, that this is not optimal, but at least it illustrates the desired output.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
    57.7200;403.7083
    81.1200;359.9954
    83.7600;2673.1575
    84.4800;201.8542
    95.7600;359.9954
    104.6400;403.7083
    104.8800;2673.1575
    105.0000;5146.4829
    105.1200;11393.4863
    105.2400;5706.3101
    105.9600;201.8542
    106.9200;4277.3057
    107.2800;359.9954
    107.4000;682.9842
    107.8800;2673.1575
    108.0000;403.7083
    108.3600;2673.1575
    108.6000;201.8542
    109.2000;47.6190
    109.4400;3883.1460
    109.9200;4081.7891
    110.0400;1113.2275
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {\textit{m/z}},
        ylabel = {Int. [\si{cps}]},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark = none, red!0] table[
            col sep = semicolon
        ] {table.csv};
        \draw[red] (57.7200,0) -- (57.7200,403.7083);
        \draw[red] (81.1200,0) -- (81.1200,359.9954);
        \draw[red] (83.7600,0) -- (83.7600,2673.1575);
        \draw[red] (84.4800,0) -- (84.4800,201.8542);
        \draw[red] (95.7600,0) -- (95.7600,359.9954);
        \draw[red] (104.6400,0) -- (104.6400,403.7083);
        \draw[red] (104.8800,0) -- (104.8800,2673.1575);
        \draw[red] (105.0000,0) -- (105.0000,5146.4829);
        \draw[red] (105.1200,0) -- (105.1200,11393.4863);
        \draw[red] (105.2400,0) -- (105.2400,5706.3101);
        \draw[red] (105.9600,0) -- (105.9600,201.8542);
        \draw[red] (106.9200,0) -- (106.9200,4277.3057);
        \draw[red] (107.2800,0) -- (107.2800,359.9954);
        \draw[red] (107.4000,0) -- (107.4000,682.9842);
        \draw[red] (107.8800,0) -- (107.8800,2673.1575);
        \draw[red] (108.0000,0) -- (108.0000,403.7083);
        \draw[red] (108.3600,0) -- (108.3600,2673.1575);
        \draw[red] (108.6000,0) -- (108.6000,201.8542);
        \draw[red] (109.2000,0) -- (109.2000,47.6190);
        \draw[red] (109.4400,0) -- (109.4400,3883.1460);
        \draw[red] (109.9200,0) -- (109.9200,4081.7891);
        \draw[red] (110.0400,0) -- (110.0400,1113.2275);
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ycomb`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{table.csv}
    57.7200;403.7083
    81.1200;359.9954
    83.7600;2673.1575
    84.4800;201.8542
    95.7600;359.9954
    104.6400;403.7083
    104.8800;2673.1575
    105.0000;5146.4829
    105.1200;11393.4863
    105.2400;5706.3101
    105.9600;201.8542
    106.9200;4277.3057
    107.2800;359.9954
    107.4000;682.9842
    107.8800;2673.1575
    108.0000;403.7083
    108.3600;2673.1575
    108.6000;201.8542
    109.2000;47.6190
    109.4400;3883.1460
    109.9200;4081.7891
    110.0400;1113.2275
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {\textit{m/z}},
        ylabel = {Int. [\si{cps}]},
    ]
        \addplot+[mark = none, red,ycomb] table[
            col sep = semicolon
        ] {table.csv};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you *very* much!

Comment: @Sam Thanks and you're welcome!

Comment: Would you please elaborate the meaning of the \addplot+ compared to \addplot?

Comment: @Diaa AFAIK `\addplot+` selects the next style from a cycle list whereas `\addplot` does not cycle through styles, see the bottom of the pgfplots manual v1.17 on p. 30. Here it should not matter (dropping the `+` may be cleaner, though), I just copied the code from the question.

Comment: P.S. `ycomb` is, of course, much more versatile than that. One can attach arrow heads, vary the line style and even decorate the path. There are other things `ybar` is good at, namely having bars that get filled, perhaps even with a pattern. That is, there is a good reason for the existence of two different plot handlers. Their basic definitions can be looked up in section **65 Plot Handler Library** of pgfmanual v3.1.6, but pgfplots modifies some things in subtle ways.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [anonymous' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569205/73317), `ycomb` can do the job. Another way is to use `ybar`. This plots each data point as a vertical bar (for horizontal bars, you would use `xbar`). The bar width can be customized using `bar width`, as in:

```latex
\begin{axis}[..., ybar, bar width=0.4pt]
    \addplot table[draw=none] {table.csv};
\end{axis}
```

As you found out yourself, `draw=none` allows one to get the precise specified width for the bars, otherwise they are drawn slightly larger due to the `draw` operation.

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
    57.7200;403.7083
    81.1200;359.9954
    83.7600;2673.1575
    84.4800;201.8542
    95.7600;359.9954
    104.6400;403.7083
    104.8800;2673.1575
    105.0000;5146.4829
    105.1200;11393.4863
    105.2400;5706.3101
    105.9600;201.8542
    106.9200;4277.3057
    107.2800;359.9954
    107.4000;682.9842
    107.8800;2673.1575
    108.0000;403.7083
    108.3600;2673.1575
    108.6000;201.8542
    109.2000;47.6190
    109.4400;3883.1460
    109.9200;4081.7891
    110.0400;1113.2275
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {\textit{m/z}},
        ylabel = {Int. [\si{cps}]},
        ybar, bar width = 0.4pt,
    ]
        \addplot+[draw=none, fill=red] table[col sep = semicolon] {table.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the `bar width` to be equal to the current PGF `line width` in the `tikzpicture`, you can use `bar width/.expanded = \the\pgflinewidth`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
    57.7200;403.7083
    81.1200;359.9954
    83.7600;2673.1575
    84.4800;201.8542
    95.7600;359.9954
    104.6400;403.7083
    104.8800;2673.1575
    105.0000;5146.4829
    105.1200;11393.4863
    105.2400;5706.3101
    105.9600;201.8542
    106.9200;4277.3057
    107.2800;359.9954
    107.4000;682.9842
    107.8800;2673.1575
    108.0000;403.7083
    108.3600;2673.1575
    108.6000;201.8542
    109.2000;47.6190
    109.4400;3883.1460
    109.9200;4081.7891
    110.0400;1113.2275
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {\textit{m/z}},
        ylabel = {Int. [\si{cps}]},
        ybar, bar width/.expanded = \the\pgflinewidth,
    ]
        \addplot+[draw=none, fill=red] table[col sep = semicolon] {table.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, of course! That's a great idea! It's a bit unfortunate though that I have to manually define the width of the bars to be equal to the `0.4pt` as is the default linewidth in Ti*k*z. What if I decide to change the default line width for the whole document? I then have to remember to change it for each `ybar` plot.

Comment: I've added an example that sets `bar width` to the current PGF line width.

Comment: This works well too, thanks for the idea! PS: As the bar plots have a draw and a fill property, you have to say `draw = none, fill = red` to get the correct line width.

Comment: That's a good point! I've updated my answer to reflect this, thanks.